# Carregando jQuery no magento apenas se ele não foi carregado antes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento, front-end

Eu preciso que o meu módulo só faça o carregamento do `jQuery` se ele ainda não tiver carregado na página, eu fiz pelo javascript, mas ele executa muito rapido, mesmo usando 'setInterval' e etc.. Em alguns casos eles continua passando sem esperar o `jQuery` carregar, a minha pergunta seria:

Como  posso carregar o `jQuery` com meu módulo apenas se ele não foi carregado antes?

Answer (score 1):

Encontrei um script no [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1828237/check-if-jquery-has-been-loaded-then-load-it-if-false) que pode te ajudar, tente adicionar este bloco de script na página que precisa realizar a validação:

```
<script>
if(!window.jQuery) // verifica se foi carregado
{
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = "text/javascript";
   script.src = "path/to/jQuery"; //caminho para carregar
   document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script); // adiciona script no HEAD
}
</script>
```

Comment: pśe eu usó algo parecido, e é por isso que precisso algo mais voltado para que ele faça essa verificação no magento, porque meu script roda antes mesmo de o jQuery ser carregado, eu tentei usar setTimeot etc.. Mas funciona em algumas páginas e em outras mais "pesadas" ele da erro.